# (High School Level) How to calculate effective resistance on parallel circuits?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, electrical-resistance

I was doing an AQA Physics Alevel (UK Syllabus) past paper and I came across this past paper question:

[image]

It asks me to 'calculate effective resistance between P and Q'. I had a few attemps in trying to get the right answer (2R) by doing things like R + R + R(1/(1/4 + 1/3 + 1/6)) and a few other methods, but in my mind theres a minimum resistance of 2 ohms in the series circuits below.

The methods I've looked up have me 'simplifying circuits', or doing other complex parallel/series work that I know can't be necessary as its an A-Level specification and we don't cover those techniques.

Any 'tips' or 'hints' would be incredibly helpful.

Comment: Try redrawing the circuit in way that maintains the structure but makes it easier to see the parallel/series connections of its subparts.

Comment: @mavzolej That sounds really useful but I'm still not entirely sure how to do that? Looking up 'simplifying circuits' brings up diagonal circuits etc - something that I can't really see here. Know any resources/useful help websites to do this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey so the **first step** to any of these problems is simply finding the current direction.
start from P and draw arrows to show how the current would move.

If the current flows through resistors without dividing, theyre in series
and if it doesn’t (and divides into many smaller currents), theyre in parallel

in the figure below, its evident that they split, hence its for sure a parallel

[image: parallel combination]

though really simple and basic, this concept is fundamental to many future, harder circuit analysis related questions

**Step two** is to break the circuit into parts, such that each one is a clear series/parallel circuit

Im starting with 6R and 3R

[image: cropped circuit 1]

Now its evident that 6R and 3R are in parallel since the current divides

We know that any parallel combination's equivalent resistance is calculated as follows

1/R = 1/R1 + 1/R2 + 1/R3 + ...

Hence, 1/eq. resistance = 1/6R + 1/3R
By this, 1/eq. resistance = 1/2R
And therefore eq. resistance = 2R

Now R, 2R (the eq. resistance of the 6R-3R combination) and R are in series since the current is unchanged
Hence for a series combination
R(eq.) = R1 + R2 + R3 + ...

Therefore, R(eq.) = R + 2R + R = 4R

[image: cropped image 2]

Here, since the current divides, our resistance is once more in parallel

1/R(eq.) = 1/R1 + 1/R2 + ....

Hence, 1/R(eq.) = 1/4R + 1/4R

1/R(eq.) = 1/2R

Therefore, the final resistance is 1/2R

Another thing, you said that you took 6R, 3R and 4R in parallel and calculated them as
1/6R + 1/3R + 1/4R
That's most likely where you made a mistake

There are 2 R-resistors between the 3R and 4R resistors which change the entire circuit
These resistors are in series with the **combination** of 3R and 6R
And so you cannot take all three resistors in series

This method is a bit long, (and I know there are faster ways to do it)
But back when I first learnt resistor combinations and circuit analysis, this was one of the most accurate, and simplest methods I found

Comment: So you've continuously narrowed down the graph into smaller and smaller sections, as if reducing the parallel sections to series sections. I find some vague similarities to recursive functions in your process. Perfectly explained. Just a teensy arithmetic answer on the final line you forgot to take the reciprocal of 1/2R to get the answer 2R. Aside from that - perfect! Time to go find some other similar practise questions.

Comment: Oh yes sorry, I think I forgot to write that last step,
But yes - no matter how complicated a circuit is, just breaking it into parts and simplifying each one always helps
And about similar practice questions, when I first started current electricity, this site was a huge help for me, I'm sending this here for your reference, it might help
http://www.ilectureonline.com/lectures/subject/PHYSICS/5/52